# Send mail with current date as subject

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com

I am using Win32com.client module to send mail to a recipient with attachment in a new outlook window, but I can't update the mail Subject with current date daily if I send it using scheduler. I need the Subject line to have the date and time of the report being sent

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch

olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "Test report for"
newMail.HTMLBody = "This is for testing"
attachment = "C:\\Users\\ibm\\test.xls"
newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
newMail.To  = "ibm@gmail.com"
newMail.Send()
print('Report mail sent Successfully!!!')
```

Actual result: 
Test report for

Expected result: 
Test report for 06/27/2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this,

```
newMail.Subject = "Test report for"
```

with,

```
newMail.Subject = "Test report for" + str(today.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
```

Do this first,

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch

today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "Test report for" + d1
newMail.HTMLBody = "This is for testing"
attachment = "C:\\Users\\ibm\\test.xls"
newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
newMail.To  = "ibm@gmail.com"
newMail.Send()
print('Report mail sent Successfully!!!')
```

import date from datetime module first and use strftime() function to get date in which format you want.